# Я считаю, что нет девушки(,) красивее, чем Вы, мэм!

Tags: орфография

Запятая ведь не нужна в обоих случаях. Так?

> Я считаю, что нет девушки(,) красивее, чем Вы, мэм!

> Нету-с никакого человека(,) более детально похожего на неё, чем Вы.

Comment: Не нужны запятые. Смысл в оборотах как раз.

Comment: Лео: «_Я считаю, что нет **дувушки(,)** красивее_…» === Дувушка – это что?  Двухкомнатная квартира?

Comment: Лео, вы постоянно задаете одинаковые вопросы и постоянно не можете запомнить правила, которые вам говорят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) *Я считаю, что нет девушки **красИвее**, чем ВЫ, мэм!*

Нет запятой, **одно ударение.** Определение является смысловым центром.

(2) *Нету-с никакого человЕка, **более детально** похОжего на неё, чем Вы.*

Запятая ставится, **два ударение**, обособление  определительного оборота. Дистантное расположение определения относительно определяемого слова.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Я **"слышу"** запятую во втором предложении, но у меня сформировалось прямо-таки **звериное чутье на произношение** (сказывается опыт интонационного анализа!). Но другие пользователи этого могут не слышать и начинают **сомневаться**. Тогда обратимся к правилам:

**[Розенталь, пункт 7(3)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)**

Определение обособляется, если 3) если **оторвано в тексте от существительного:** Глаза смыкались и, полузакрытые, тоже улыбались (Т.); На лавке, разбросанные, лежали поршни, ружьё (Л. Т.); Настасья Петровна ещё раз обняла Егорушку, обозвала его ангельчиком и, заплаканная, стала собирать на стол (Ч.);

*Нету-с никакого человЕка, **более детально** похОжего на неё, чем Вы.*

Вы видите, что прилагательное ***похожего*** находится на расстоянии от существительного ***человека***. Обособление **обязательно!**

Сочетание "более детально" препятствует **переходу** ударения с существительного на прилагательное (поэтому здесь два ударения).

Comment: Мнение о языке (кардинально! Не буду говорить, в какую сторону, думаю, вы подозреваете) да и вы сами тоже поменялись, не я один... Раньше было лучше. И не только в ближайшем _раньше_, в принципе раньше на этом сайте лучше было.

Comment: Я думаю, не хватает варианта: я считаю что нет, девушки красивее, чем вы, сэр...

Comment: @Максим  А вы это об чем?  Я стараюсь меняться только в  лучшую сторону. Или у вас появились сомнения? Мой уровень знаний стал выше, как я думаю.

Comment: @Буратино Опять меня смешите! У вас талант)  Но пример этот у Лео, кстати,  хорош. С точки зрения грамматики и пунктуации.

Comment: И всё-таки нужна там запятая, хоть мне и не хочется её ставить: считаю, что нет.

Comment: Докажите, сэр. У меня грамматическое (по правилам)  и интонационное решение. В первом предложении не нужна запятая, а во втором нужна.  А что у вас?